# Почему смазывается вся верстка в .dialog (jquery), если в диалог вставлено видео с ютуба?

Tags: jquery-ui, html, iframe

**Здравствуйте!**

Имеет место следующая проблема, **всплывающее окно .dialog()** c вертикальной прокруткой **содержит** внутри себя **iframe** содержащий видео с ютуба, **при прокрутке смазывается все содержимое** диалогового окна и только видео отображается корректно, если после прокрутки выделить мышкой содержимое окна, то все отрисовывается как и должно быть. Есть предположение что браузер не успевает отрисовывать контент? (Браузер Google Chrome). Хотелось бы понять, почему так происходит и каким образом избежать данной проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Есть предположение что это глюк именно Вашего браузера. Попробуйте проверить на другом компе.

Comment: Не в компе дело. Проверял и на другой платформе.

Comment: Залейте на хостинг и дайте ссылку.